Сложный момент с обособлением слова "например": нужна ли запятая?
Нужна ли запятая после слова "например" в предложении:
А тут обморочный туман, например (,) как вы на битве использовали.

В качестве варианта:
А тут обморочный туман — например, как вы на битве использовали.
Пояснение
Это БСП, две предикативные основы, присоединительные отношения обозначены тире. При постановке запятой неясно определяется структура предложения.
